# Поменять ссылку на чат на странице выборов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, чат, выборы

Можно пожалуйста поменять ссылку на [странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election), которая ведёт в чат, поменять с https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/145259 на https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145259/2023-stack-overflow---moderator-election-chat?

Возможно я чего-то не знаю и/или из-за количества репутации не вижу каких-то дополнительных шагов для вступления в этот чат. Простите в таком случае :)

Жутко раздражает каждый раз нажимать на кнопку `join this room`

Comment: Это могут сделать только сотрудники, но я попробую пингануть кого-нибудь в модераторской. UPD: Grundy уже пинганул Catija.

Comment: @Nofate но тогда будет не посмотреть статистику, не заходя в чат.

Comment: так ведь можно жмануть по "info" на плашке чата в [общем списке](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Nofate в мобильной версии такого нет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Это уже недочёты мобильной версии :) Ну и всегда можно врубить версию для компа

Comment: Там пишут, что ссылку не поправить, так как ее движок генерит. Расходимся.

Comment: @Nofate Ну так ничего не мешает поменять шаблон :) Но Catija потом спросила, удобнее было бы поменять ссылку? На что Grundy ответил "Да". Потому буду надеяться что это исправят :)

Comment: всегда можно, но не всегда удобно. Так же как и "join this room" можно всегда нажать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Согласен, хороший аргумент) Но мне кажется что статистикой чата пользуются реже чем самим чатом, потому ссылка в чат мне кажется удобнее чем ссылка на инфо страницу

Comment: > "Ну так ничего не мешает поменять шаблон"
Так это глобальный change request уже. ПМ должен согласовать и таску поставить, разраб поправить шаблон, куа потестить. Мы тут на такое привыкли не надеяться.